# Using git on my server update worktree and www directory with new versions?

Tags: git, bash, server

Let's say I am building a UI and I have a version with a particular layout and scheme we can call it v0.0.1, it's nice but I decide I want to change some drastic layout features, fonts, colors etc and say I call this new version v0.0.2.

I `tag` first project, `git tag -a v0.0.1 -m 'first version'` then I push it to the server `git push live master` where I have a hook (push command triggers post-receive bash script) which takes the repo files and sends it to my live directory which the client can preview.

The files are served `www/example.com/public_html/clients/john/dist` what I would like to do is possibly in the `post-receive` bash script look for a new tag then run a linux command like `mkdir v0.0.2` so that the worktree changes to `www/example.com/public_html/clients/john/v0.0.2/dist`

So I wanted to ask, what is a proper way in updating my worktree and creating a new folder with new pushed versions?

Comment: What is your `post-receive` hook doing right now? It seems that the only piece you are missing is creating the directory based on the available tag? Do you want a new directory only on new tags? Where do other changes go? Also remember that git is [not a deployment tool](http://gitolite.com/deploy.html).

Comment: The hook does a checkout `#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/var/www/domain.com --git-dir=/var/repo/site.git checkout -f` really you shouldn't use it for deployment? Yeah ideally trivial changes stick to the current version, but significant changes with a new tag go to a new directory. So this is where I am not sure how to approach, like how would I evaluate if there is a new tag, is it optimal to make a new directory from the bash script?

Comment: `git describe --abbrev=0` shows you the most recent tag reachable from a given commit.

Comment: Okay, so would this take a bit of bash scripting? I mean it sounds like I would need to evaluate `if git describe --abbrev=0 != previous version` then `cd ../../../www/example.com/public_html/clients/john/ && mkdir v.0.02` then `checkout -f` or something along those lines, obviously not perfect, but is it ideal to manage this operation via post-receive?

Comment: Something like that only you don't need to care about the `if` bit, just always use the output from that describe command (if you want to continue using a directory of the last tag which is slightly odd just for the record). Doing any of this in post-receive isn't ideal (as that link I posted discusses). Continuous deployment systems exist for this sort of thing (though they may be overkill for simple cases).

Comment: so use `git describe --abbrev=0` as variable? like `#!/bin/sh git --work-tree=/var/www/domain.com/git describe --abbrev=0 --git-dir=/var/repo/site.git checkout -f`? What about `mkdir` I surely don't want to use it everytime? Could you provide a basic example, and I will give your credit!

Comment: Also what is the difference between, `git tag` & `git describe --abbrev=0`. I am just curious how I would use that inside the bash script? I guess for now I can create the version folders manually.

Comment: You absolutely can just run `mkdir -p` every time if you want but you could also test for the directory first if you want and only make it if it doesn't exist (but that's not something I generally recommend because it is usually pointless). And yes, get the output from `git describe ...` and use it in the path to the work-tree. `git tag` lists all the (matching) tags. `git describe` "describes" the current commit as related to the most recent reachable tag (and `--abbrev=0` says to drop the "relative path" part of the generated output, try without it to see what you get and read the man page).

Comment: Awesome man, sorry everything was transparent until I actually tried it, now it all makes sense. Props to you man, thanks for your time and knowledge!