# How to write a bash script that creates a new folder version?

Tags: git, bash

I guess git is not a deployment tool, however, for the last year I have been using `git checkout -f` inside `post-receive` without any issues.

*post-receive hook*

```
#!/bin/sh
git --work-tree=/var/www/domain.com --git-dir=/var/repo/site.git checkout -f
```

Now I want to further things by doing some version control & git tagging.

For example I have an updated version of my project *(v0.2)* I feel it's better, however there may have been some nice features removed in *(v0.1)* that I still want to see and compare, also for many other reasons as well.

- A. Should I handle this functionality inside the bash script?
- B. What should the code look like?

Below is my interpretation of what the code would like like, my question is how do I actually make the below work optimally?

```
#!/bin/sh
$version = git tag
if ($version != $previousVersion) {
  mkdir ../../../www/domain.com/$version/
}
git --work-tree=/var/www/domain.com/$version --git-dir=/var/repo/site.git checkout -f
```

Obviously some flaws above, and plus I don't really know bash scripting, so I am going to read on creating variables and booleans.

With the above my question is what is the best way to write the logic, i.e compare versions (which is not even possible to check above because `$previousVersion` doesn't exist, I am not exactly sure how to check the last pushed commit's version, or if that is even a thing).

So I would like to learn what operations need to be done in the `post-receive` so that if there is a new `git tag` a new folder is created in my `--work-tree` aka `/var/www/domain.com` and the checkout pushes the files there.

Comment: You seem to be ignoring the suggestions I gave you on your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29758876/258523) here. Don't compare just always use the current tag. Don't use `git tag` use `git describe --abbrev=0`. (Though like I said having post-version-tag changes in a versioned directory is a bit odd.) Why the relative path in the mkdir but an absolute path in the git command?

Comment: I wasn't completely confident, I know what you suggested is right, you obviously know your stuff, but it wasn't 100% clear to me as far as placement and actual code. I was hoping for an answer, where I can read some code and avoid making critical mistakes. I feel like I might have screwed something up and mess up my working tree, because it's currently being used for a client to view the UI I am building. I am just doing it manually right now.

Comment: For example do I need to store `git describe --abbrev=0` in a variable? like `$version = git describe --abbrev=0`, does it not matter, I mean how does it parse that command, wouldn't it read it as an actual directory and try to push to `/site/git describe` lol?

Comment: Add a second block of code to your script. Use a test directory in that second block and try it. Yes, `recenttag=$(git --git-dir=/var/repo/site.git describe --abbrev=0)`. Alternatively set up an entirely separate "server" to test this on until you get it right.

Comment: And to answer your question above, because I am a noob lol

Comment: Maybe since its a command it is different? I am coming from javascript/php so I am just used to that, and applying my knowledge of how those get compiled, but with the bash script, being that its not a string but a command it should just work

Comment: Anyways, let me just hack away at a test dir... Thanks MAN!!!

Comment: Aha, got it to work, just was being kind of skeptical along the way, in a way I still am, I am scared this may get sloppy, but for now it's pretty awesome. I think as long as with .gitignore I ignore all development files and send only the minified dist js,css,html files, then my server will be able to handle it.